# Why is my print statement not showing up in django runserver?

Tags: python, django

I've been using django for only 3 days and the biggest problem that I've had with it is that i can't `print()` stuff with it in the runsever terminal i'm using django 2.1.5 this is what I've done

```
def test(request):

   print('test')

   return HttpResponse('test')
```

the code works fine but it's not displaying the `print()`, it seems to work with everyone else is maybe there's another way to display it to the terminal?
I've tried using python logging as well it's still not displaying anything

P.S  sorry for such a simple question but i'm that kind of guy that can't read documentation

Comment: Are you running your app on debug mode? have you set DEBUG=True?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the code works fine"*?

Comment: I think, he meant he is getting correct http response as expected but not printing the log on console.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i mean i was fine it display what i want to display but the 'print()' that usually showed up in the runserver didn't

Comment: @Tasnuva it's True

Comment: did you solve this? I tested a new app today and the same..